# I want to capitalize the value of the php string in this echo block

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my block of php I want to capitalize the first letter in the value the string returns from `$user->data['username_clean']`

The method I tried didn't work with this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method

It is likely however that I formatted it incorrectly.  php code is here.

```
<?php 
if ($user->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS) {
   echo '
        <li class="dropdown">
           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Login<span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <form id="loginform" method="post" action="/forums/ucp.php?mode=login">
                 <label>Username</label>
                 <input name="username" type="text" id="username" class="width120 textbox" tabindex="1" />
                 <label>Password</label>
                 <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="width120 textbox" tabindex="2" />
                  <label>Remember Me?:</label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="autologin">
                  <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
                  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="indextest.php"
              </form>
        </li>';
} else { 
    echo '
        <li class=dropdown>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">',  $user->data['username_clean'], '<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">User Control Panel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
        </li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You could use [ucfirst](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ucfirst.asp) to capitalize the first letter of the sting

Comment: So how would that look in the code?
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">',  ucfirst($user->data['username_clean']), '<span class="caret"></span></a>

Comment: Look at @RiggsFolly's answer

Comment: Be sure to accept the appropriate answer too (the checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uppercase the first character of a string use

```
ucfirst( $user->data['username_clean'] );
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Uppercase the first character using `ucfirst` like so:

```
ucfirst( $user->data['username_clean'] );
```

> **ucfirst** — Make a string's first character uppercase
>
> **Description**
>
> *string ucfirst ( string $str )*
>
> **Source**
>
> http://php.net/ucfirst

And, an alternative and kind of creative solution would be to do this (fun to think about although you will probably not want to do this):

```
$user->data['username_clean']{0} = strtoupper($user->data['username_clean']{0});
```

You are accessing the first character `{0}` and changing it to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

[ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) is the PHP function to capitalize the first letter in a string.

So, you need to wrap the value you want to capitalize in that call.

Try changing:

```
 $user->data['username_clean'],
```

to:

```
ucfirst($user->data['username_clean']),
```